# Artifacts with CSS box-shadow and transition

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This works in Firefox, IE and Safari but on Chrome it shows artifacts (lines).
It's a simple CSS with :hover, box-shadow and transition.

[image: Chrome Artifacts (black lines)]

The HTML is a representation of the Periodic Table, and whenever the mouse hovers on an element it 'lights'. You can see a portion of the HTML here: [Periodic Table](http://storage.cet.ac.il/temp/periodic/index.html), where the symptom duplicates in Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create a reduced test case and find the minimum amount of code to reproduce this problem.

Comment: alright, i'm on it.. will report back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Google Chrome (newest version) and don't see the problem you're mentioning- maybe this is an issue with Chrome itself (an older version of it, at least.) Perhaps you should update your Chrome, or post an issue at the [Chromium bugs list](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

EDIT: [This may be your problem](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142038&q=lines%20hover&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary).

(Also, the text inside the elements does not look like the posted screenshot- the numbers are in line with the letters. This isn't the problem you mentioned, just something I noticed.)

Comment: Agreed, I'm on Chrome 23 and see no issue. (Win7 x64)

Comment: I don't see it either using Chrome 22 on Mac OS X ML.

Comment: I Am using the latest Chrome both at work and at home. 
At work I could reproduce the problem, while at home I can only reproduce it if I MANUALLY ZOOM-IN with 'ctrl +'. Also if I change the bitmap background to a solid color (#333 for example) the artifacts will not reproduce. I assume it has something to do with hardware acceleration and texture mapping. Should I report a bug to Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

This looks not like an user/script error, more than a bug in the Browser, as mentioned above. Test it in other Browsers and update your Chrome, maybee clear cache. More you can not do.

Comment: Btw. you could edit your css minimaly, e.g increase the shadow by 1Pixel, this could fix it.

Comment: I found out that if I remove the margins from the div nested in td, the artifacts are minimized but still exist.

Comment: So this seems to be a browser bug. Waiting for the next Chromium version will (hopefully) fix this.